# AJAX Caching issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Ok a lot of answered articles about this have been dealing with POST and whatnot, but this is for none of those reasons.

I do realize I could use the .load() function which I have and it still caches it that way. It said through AJAX, they had a cache attribute you could set to false so I switched methods. However, they both result the same...

```
        $.ajax({
                url: "<?= $GLOBALS['SECURE_AREA']."inline/login_status.php?call_letters=$GLOBALS[call_letters]&t=".rand(100,999)."" ?>",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#user_info").html(data);
                }
        });
        //$("#user_info").load("<?= $GLOBALS['SECURE_AREA']."inline/login_status.php" ?>");
```

The url does exist. When I go to it, it displays the results correctly that I want. However this is still displaying the very first load it gave.. and not refreshing since after you login, the content changes.. It's still saying "Signup | Login".. Not "My Account"

Any idea on how to fix this? The AJAX and .load() method both do not work for me. They both cache.

Comment: you are attempting to access PHP variables with JavaScript. no-can-do buddy.

Comment: Probably not the issue, but `rand(100,999)` has a really high collision, try using `time()` or `microtime()` instead.

Comment: YOu don't really  need the rand(100,999) at all, jquery will add one of those for you due to `cache: false`. Are you running this ajax request after the user logs in?

Comment: Actually @sircapsalot, you can. It shows the variable I'm trying to echo it so yes.. you can. Time() and microtime() both do not work still. I'm running the AJAX request on every single page even before they login so yes..

Comment: @Peanut in your code, you don't actually specify that you are echoing out. NOR does it include that you are even using PHP. i'll add that tag in. but echoing it will let you achieve your results. as my answer states

Comment: <?= is the short hand for <?php echo... o.o

Answer (score 0):

I can offer an alternative -

With PHP, you can echo the data you need directly into the page... for example

```
<?php echo <<<JS
    $.ajax({
        url: "\"".$GLOBALS['SECURE_AREA'] . "inline/login_status.php?call_letters=".$GLOBALS['call_letters']."&t=".time()."\"", // per @phpissuper01
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#user_info").html(data);
        }
    });
JS;
?>
```

What this will do will execute your ajax when this is placed in, and since only PHP can access the `$GLOBALS` var, you can echo out what you need.

Furthermore, You have several issues with string concatenation in your code which contributed to the errors, which are fixed in this answer

Comment: That looks really good, but I think the concatenation is still off as it gives me this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /usr/home/websites/content/mogadore-deals.com/public_html/includes/template_9/header.php on line 24     Which is the "url: etc....." line.

Comment: @Peanut try now - all i did was add the "<url here>" quotes around the url that it was generating. that was most likely your issue.

Comment: Still a syntax error on the same line.. I have already tried messing with it and can't seem to get it since I've never messed with <<<JS stuff in PHP.

Comment: the <<<* is just a way to echo mass text.  The rest is with you man.. where you should start is the url.  step through and debug.. echo out the entire url: line so you can see what the url actually is.